# how to return a string in multiline in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to return the values of the variables in multiline.

page.ts

```
//all imports are done

export class page {

let title1: string;
let heading: string;
let heading2: string;
let heading4 : string;

constructor(){}

public onClick(){   //from html I am calling this onClick()
   return testFunction(); 
}

public testFunction(){
return this.title1 + '\ '+ this.heading + '\ '+ this.heading2 + '\ ' + this.heading4;
}
}
```

// display -->

```
ABCD Today is very cold here What about there?
How are you?
```

Expected output -->

```
                    ABCD

                    Today is very cold here

                    What about there?

                    How are you?
```

AS 
title1 = ABCD

heading1 = Today is very cold here.

heading2 = What about there?

heading4 = How are you?

Comment: You can wrap each variable around `<br>` tag to add a new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**ES6 template literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which is also supported in Typescript. The rest adjustment you can do yourself

```
public testFunction(){
     return `${this.title1}
             ${this.heading}
             ${this.heading2}
             ${this.heading4}`;
}
```

Comment: It is returning the variable names itself not the values

Comment: like this.title1

Comment: in angular2 also shall I use the same design?

Comment: This is ES6 syntax, not language specific. So you can use this whereever your runtime supports ES6